# Remove Specific Value From List In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I have a list of values, these are all a combination of letters and numbers, to make an ID, however on some occasions this can just simply be a 0.

I need to remove all occasions where this is a 0.

I've tried something like

```
For i = 0 the list.count - 1
   If list(i) = "0" Then
       list.RemoveAt(j)
   End If
Next
```

But this then throws an argument out of range exception at the end because the loop continues, and I can't use Exit For because I need to check for multiple zeros.

I'm not very good at the Lamda expressions that seem to do what I want, and don't understand them, so if someone could give and explain one that would work, that'd be brilliant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start from the end of the list and go backwards toward 0

```
For i = list.count - 1 to 0 Step -1
   If list(i) = "0" Then
       list.RemoveAt(j)
   End If
Next
```

If you want to use linq with a lambda use Where to keep all items that are not equal to "0" and recreate the list with `ToList`

```
list = list.Where(function(value) value <> "0").ToList
```

The lamda in this case is the same as

```
Function IsNotZero(value As String) As Boolean
    return value <> "0"
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

using LINQ or lambda expressions would be fairly easy solution to this problem.

The IEnumerable(Of T) interface contains a method called [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx). This function can seem a bit daunting because it takes in a rather nasty looking parameter but it really isn't as bad as it looks.

So the parameter passed into [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) can be an anonymous function or an address to a function. For this case an anonymous function is the way to go.

To remove all the objects from a list of strings where a condition is met you can use:

```
list.RemoveAll(Function(o) o="0")
```

This short line of code is actually doing quite a few things. First its creating an anonymous function that takes in a string as a parameter and returns the result of the comparison of that string to the literal "0". Next the [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) function uses that anonymous function to evaluate all the members of the `list` and removes the object if the anonymous function evaluates to true.

**Alternative:**

The same code could be done with a function pointer. This method results in a bit more code but allows you to do a lot more in your comparison logic than just compare each value to a literal.

We still call the [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) function like before but this time we pass the address of a function that has the signature similar to `Public Function <FunctionName>(byval Param As String) As Boolean` if the signature does not match then you will get an error.

```
List.RemoveAll(AddressOf TestFunction)
```

Next we define the function off somewhere else in the program.

```
Public Function TestFunction(ByVal item As String) As Boolean
    return item = "0"
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to loop backwards

```
For i = thelist.count - 1 to 0 step -1
```

Because you are going backwards you don't have to worry about shifting the items down as you go and messing up your index.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be creating new list which doesn't contain "0"-values

```
Dim newlist As List(Of String) = list.Where(function(v) v.Equals("0") = false).ToList()
```